# How to reuse a custom object serializer for a list of objects?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, serialization, jackson

I've written a custom "student" serializer and want to reused it for a list of student. Do I need to write a new Serializer for the Type `List<Student>` or can I reuse `StudentSerializer`?

For example:

```
class Student(
var id: Long? = null,
var name: String? = null,
var courses: MutableList<Courses> = mutableListOf()
)
```

```
class Course(
var id: Long? = null,
var name: String? = null,
var students: MutableList<Student> = mutableListOf()
)
```

```
class StudentSerializer : JsonSerializer<Student>() {

    override fun serialize(student: Student?, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider?) {
     gen.writeStartObject()
     // ...
     gen.writeEndObject()
    }
 }
```

How can I reuse this Serializer for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to write a new Serializer for the Type List or can
> I reuse StudentSerializer

You can reuse the `StudentSerializer` serializer already defined: in your case you can annotate your `students`field in the `Course` class with the `JsonSerialize` annotation with [`contentUsing`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#contentUsing--) directive where `contentusing` indicates the serializer class to use for serializing contents (elements of a Collection/array, values of Maps) of one annotated property:

```
class Course(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing= StudentSerializer::class)
    var students: MutableList<Student> = mutableListOf()
)
```